# jQuery $(this) is confused

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a several forms on a page which are all sort of identical.  Some of the forms have a css class on some of the elements which is used to bind an onchange event handler.  The environment is ASP.NET MVC.

```
$('.check-changes').on('change', function () {
    var parent = $(this).parents('form');
    var parentId = parent.attr('id');
    var trackChangeId = '#' + parentId + ' [name="Changed"]';
    $(trackChangeId).val('True');
});
```

So we track the changes to elements and it should update an input within the same form.  Each form is an instance of a partial view, so all the elements have the same names, etc.  Mostly this works well with dropdowns and other kinds of inputs.  However, checkboxes seem to be a problem.  Clicking a checkbox in the second form the parent is determined to be  the first form, so that is what gets updated.  These are bootstrap/mvc checkboxes, so not only does the event tell me the parent form is the wrong one it also shows as the same checkbox in the other form being checked or unchecked.

So in each form we have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsSpecial, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "custom-control-input monitor-change" } })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSpecial)
```

If I click IsSpecial in Form 1, it checks and unchecks and the monitor does its thing.  But if I click it in Form 2, nothing happens to the one in Form 2.  Instead Form1 IsSpecial gets checked and unchecked and the monitor does the Form 1 things.  $(this) and parent are the ID of Form 1 when stepping through the function.

I don't know if it's a bootstrap problem or if I just need to get more specific with the ID of the checkbox element.  Maybe manually build the checkboxes instead of letting .NET do it.

Comment: Check boxes have a property for `checked` that is not associated with the Value. If you know you are selecting a check box, use `$('selector').prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Honestly the monitor thing doesn't even matter anymore with this implementation. I just got lucky I had left it in place after changing the layout to include multiple form elements instead of one big form.  In the previous implementation with one big form each of the inputs had a name that was like FormName.InputName and Id like FormName_InputName for the name and it just worked.  Maybe I need to change my approach and go with a manually constructed checkbox instead of the .NET one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I think the issue was the heavily customized version of bootstrap I was using combined with the ASP.NET MVC checkboxes with identical ID and Name causing the problem.  I changed how the partial view is implemented, giving both checkboxes unique ID's and then it worked.  A few script changes later and everything is firing as expected.

I was never able to reproduce the issue in a stock bootstrap environment even with identical ID and names which is why I think it is partially due to the custom bootstrap being used in this scenario.